# Closed form for $L$ in $LL^T=XX^T-Diag(XX^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I want to write $XX^T-Diag(XX^T)$ into $LL^T$. $Diag(XX^T)$ is a diagonal matrix with only diagonal values in $XX^T$ on it. Can I get the closed form solution of $L$?

As pointed out, $XX^T-diag(XX^T)$ is not positive semi-definite. What if we fix it by $XX^T-Diag(XX^T)+\max\{diag(XX^T)\}I$. Then is it possible?

Comment: $XX^T - \operatorname{diag}(XX^T)$ is not positive semidefinite apart when it is the zero matrix.

Comment: @user251257 General question: is possible always to write $\text{diag}(A)=PAQ$ for any square $A$ and for some $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: @yurnero:  Perhaps your Comment would work better as a new Question with slightly more context added to it.  When $P,Q$ are restricted to invertible matrices, you get a matrix $PAQ$ which is *equivalent* to $A$.   Possibly you are asking about the diagonal entries of $A$ being equivalent to $A$?  (Consider an antisymmetric real matrix.)

Comment: @hardmath I understand your advice. I just hoped that I could get a quick answer. I did mean $\text{diag}(A)=PAQ$ where $=$ is taken as literal and I was hoping that $P$ and $Q$ would *not* depend on $A$.

Comment: @user251257 I changed the problem.

Comment: The formula for cholesky decomposition is basically a closed form. Although it might be possible that the matrix is not positive definite. I am not sure what you expect...

Comment: @user251257 Because $XX^T$ is too large, I can not put it in the memory and so can not use cholesky:(

Comment: What is $X$? a vector or a matrix?

Comment: @draks... $X_{N\times d}$

Comment: yeah but $XX^T + D$ would be even worse, wouldn't it? What are you trying to do? solving linear equations? Perhaps you should try iterative solvers.

Comment: @user251257 I want to get $(I + XX^T+D)^{-1}$. If I can write $LL^T=XX^T+D$, then I can use matrix inverse lemma:)

Comment: @E.J. is $N >> d$? If it is, you could update the cholesky decomposition of $I+D$ (which is trivial)

Comment: @user251257 Yes. $N>>d$. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @user251257 what is $D$ is not diagonal but symmetric.

Comment: @E.J. Ah, okay. I thought it was diagonal. Does it has any other structure?

Comment: @user251257 No:(. Thanks though:)

Comment: @E.J. Do you really want to compute the inverse of $I+XX^T + D$? Otherwise I would suggest some low rank approximation of $D$.

Answer (score 2):

Not in general, as the following example shows:
$X=\pmatrix{1\\1}$, then
$$
XX^T-\text{diag}(XX^T)=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}-\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\ne LL^T
$$

Comment: I changed the problem.

Comment: @E.J. I changed my answer...

Comment: $L=I$? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @user251257 oh I focussed too much on projectors...